# Using one massive map service vs multiple smaller services in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, performance, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have a Silverlight application that consumes around 30 map service layers at different types.  The service layers are categorized based on type and only applicable to certain screens of the application.

For organization's sake, I split each of the layer categories into separate map services, but I'm considering whether or not that makes sense.

Should I just lump all of the map layers into a massive map service or keep them separate?

I'm curious about server load vs application performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use multiple map services to take advantage between dynamic vs cached (tiled) services.  For basemap data that does not change often you should use cached services (this will improve performance).

Comment: Good point.  In this case, all of them are dynamic.  Some are being consumed as dynamic while others feature layers.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest multiple services, whether they're cached or not. I've often found that once a web map is available, a decision maker (boss) sees it and wants a similar app with only one or two of the same layers. If those layers are already in separate services then making the similar app will be quicker.